# Can Nepo and Ding receive computer analysis from teammates between tiebreak rounds?

Tags: rules, tournament, world-championship

In round 4 of the tiebreaks for the 2023 world championship ([LiChess](https://lichess.org/broadcast/fide-world-chess-championship-2023/tie-breaks/jCs1wd0E/8QvKR1zU)), Nepo played the surprise 13.Bb1.  I'm wondering if Nepo's teammates may have done a computer analysis of this position, which also occurred in round 2, and communicated to this to Nepo between rounds (during rest time).  I'm not sure if this is allowed.

**Question**: Can Nepo and Ding receive computer analysis from teammates between tiebreak rounds?

Comment: Interesting question. I could rationalize either allowing or prohibiting, though prohibiting would be logistically more complicated...

Comment: @paulgarrett Prohibiting is easy if you do not let them out of the playing venue.

Comment: @Minot, ah, until I read the answer below, I had not realized that the gaps between games were so short! No rest!?!

Comment: @paulgarrett Between all the 4 games of the tiebreak round, it was 10 mins. I don't know of the break between the rounds if game 4 ended up being a draw

Answer (score 8):

Very likely **no**, notwithstanding any fairness issues of allowing communication after the round starts, the [regulations](https://handbook.fide.com/files/handbook/FWCM2023.pdf) of the 2023 FIDE World Championship state:

> **4. 10. 2.** Except with the permission of the Chief Arbiter, only the players, the FIDE principals, one media professional from the organising team, and stewards are allowed in the playing area. **The players may communicate with an arbiter or a steward.**

This implies that to get external analysis, they would need to leave the playing venue.

This sounds impossible as the inter-round time is 10 minutes, this would have been contrary to the playing venue rules to step out and back in that timeframe :

> **4. 10. 4.** The players shall arrive at the playing area at least ten minutes before the beginning of the game for the security check.